# Keyboard Interrupt not exiting cleanly

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having sockets code in which I am handling clients through threads. The use case is like this,
1. Server runs and clients start connecting to it.
2. After their interaction clients issue exit message and server closes the client connection.
3. However what i want is in case something happens on server and if i manually hit ctrl-c on server it should exit all threads and main program as well.

Below is what i was trying but unfortunately not everything gets cleaned up and i have to hit ctrl-c twice.

```
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # This is to prevent the socket going into TIME_WAIT status and OSError
    # "Address already in use"
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
except socket.error as e:
    print('Error occured while creating the socket {}'.format(e))

server_address = ('localhost', 50000)
sock.bind(server_address)

print('**** Server started on {}:{} ****'.format(*server_address))

sock.listen(5)


def client_thread(conn_sock, client_add):
    while True:
        client_msg = conn_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        if client_msg.lower() != 'exit':
            print('[{0}:{1}] {2}'.format(*client_add, client_msg))
            serv_reply = 'Okay ' + client_msg.upper()
            conn_sock.send(bytes(serv_reply, 'utf-8'))
        else:
            conn_sock.close()
            print('{} exitted !!'.format(client_add[0]))
            sys.exit()


try:
    # Keep the server until there are incominmg connections
    while True:
        # Wait for the connctions to accept
        conn_sock, client_add = sock.accept()
        print('Recieved connection from {}:{}'.format(*client_add))
        conn_sock.send(
            bytes('***** Welcome to {} *****'.format(server_address[0]), 'utf-8'))
        Thread(target=client_thread, args=(conn_sock, client_add)).start()

except Exception as e:
    print('Some error occured \n {}'.format(e))
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print('Program execution cancelled by user')
    sys.exit(0)

finally:
    sock.close()
```

Below is the execution trace of my code

```
**** Server started on localhost:50000 ****
Recieved connection from 127.0.0.1:35910
[127.0.0.1:35910] ,msdasda
^CProgram execution cancelled by user
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/apps/nttech/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/nttech/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1294, in _shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/apps/nttech/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1056, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/apps/nttech/rbhanot/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So can anyone suggest how can i close everything when keyboardInterrupt  occures.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by making the threads as daemon, so that main program will exit on receiving the KeyboardInterrupt and threads will keep on running in background.